# Get the last names that start with a specific letter

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

```
authors = ['Audre Lorde', 'William Carlos', 'Gabriela Mistral', 'Jean Toomer', 'An Qi', 'Walt Whitman', 'Shel Silverstein', 'Carmen Boullosa', 'Kamala Suraiyya', 'Langston Hughes', 'Adrienne Rich', 'Nikki Giovanni']
```

In this list, I want to get the names that have last names start with (let's say 'S') in Python.
How do I do that? To be honest, I have no clue where to start as I am still a beginner, I tried join and split but they brought only the last name itself.

Comment: Is your input a single CSV string, or a list of string names?

Comment: This is a perfect place for a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Once you have an actual list of authors, you want a list of each name for names in the list of authors if the second part of the name, when [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) by a space, [starts with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) the letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your learning.

The list in question is not well formed.

Let's assume it is well formed. Below is simple example.

```
authors = ['Audre Lorde', 'William Carlos', 'Gabriela Mistral', 'Jean Toomer']

newlist = [x for x in authors if x.split(" ")[1].startswith('C')]
```

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I was looking for a quick example on the internet and I didn't notice the mistakes. Thanks for your help, I tried your code on an example and it worked, however in my project it showed me an error 'list index out of range'.

Comment: That means there is a name in the list that does not have the second component. Does your list include Cher, maybe? If so, you should first decide what to do with people that don't have a last name.

Comment: Yes, you're right, there's a name without a last name.

Answer (score 1):

Matching names can be difficult because you can have multiple first and last names, see this page for a nice read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

If you can have a single name as well, you can take the last entry after splitting:

```
authors = ['Audre Lorde', 'William Carlos', 'Gabriela Mistral', 'Jean Toomer', 'Cher']

print([a for a in authors if a.split(" ")[-1].startswith('C')])
```

If you want to for example check the number of splitted parts and do not want to allow single names:

```
for a in authors:
    parts = a.split(" ")
    if len(parts) > 1 and parts[1].startswith('C'):
        print(parts[1])
```